Accessing MQ Queue statistics when the QMGR lives on an MQ Appliance
I have tried using the amqsmon program provided with distributed (Linux) MQ install samples. There does not seem to be a way to authenticate with that utility, it seems to be meant to run locally on the machine where the QMGR lives using an existing user with authentication based on the local OS.
What I'm trying to do is access the same data from a QMGR that is on an MQ appliance and I'm trying to access if from a Linux server. On that server I have a user that is set up with permissions in the MQ Appliance for doing things like getting queue depth and things like that and it works fine.
I just don't seem to see a way in the usage error statement or the C program to include a userid and password to access the channels. My C skills are VERY old and I don't see the Java samples in the install anymore, was hoping there was a amqsmon.java file, that one I could modify.
I tried setting up my client side like Mark and Morag suggest in this post IBM MQ Remotely connect and query QueueStatistics like amqsmon but it does not seem to cover the userid/password issue I'm running into because the appliance has it's own users and does not depend on the remote OS for it.
At this point I'm thinking that amsqmon is not going to work for me. Does anyone know of a different way to do this that does not involve more licensed product?
SOLVED: Following the links and advice from Morag and Josh I was finally able to get it working. My issue was that I needed an additional CHLAUTH record for the specific user since we have CHLAUTH enabled.  Thanks so much for your help Morag and Josh!

You world just use a CCDT.  In the client channel definition you can specify to use the mqccred client security exit to send a username and password,  or you can send acert of your SVRCONN on the appliance is set up that way.

+1 for @JoshMc answer - agree, amqsmon0.c source code shows that it does not, within the code, provide the user id and password from anywhere, so mqccred client side exit was exactly designed for just this purpose. If you need full details, I'm sure one of us can write an answer if you need it.

P.S. -1 to whomever voted to close this very well written, pertinent question.

Thanks for the help, I'm now reading the statistics queue!!

Little further along I realize that the instructions provided said "Temporarily disable CHLAUTH" ... but they never said when to enable it again. When I do everything breaks again. I get a mqrc 2035 when trying to connect now. We use CHLAUTH for all our application SVRCONN connections.

What shows up in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG when you get the 2035?

I also tried with passing the channel ID ... same results ... I'm missing something but I can't put a finger on it.

If you are still having problems, can you update your question text with the details. It's hard to figure out what's up from the comments.

This problem is solved. Thanks so much for your help Morag and Josh! I just need to add a CHLAUTH record to allow mqm users to access the channel.
